# Does Windows support additional custom fields in file version information of an executable?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, fileversioninfo

I am writing some code in Lazarus I want to add additional information like, FPC version, Lazarus Version, Git Commit etc.

Is it possible to add fields like this in the project?

The information at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx gives these fields as the standard ones.

```
Name
Comments
CompanyName
FileDescription
FileVersion
InternalName
LegalCopyright
LegalTrademarks
OriginalFilename
PrivateBuild
ProductName
ProductVersion
SpecialBuild
```

There is also example code like

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             3,10,349,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.10.349.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          3,10,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "3.10\0"

#ifndef DEBUG
#define VER_DEBUG                   0
#else
#define VER_DEBUG                   VS_FF_DEBUG
#endif

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
FILEFLAGSMASK   VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEFLAGS       (VER_PRIVATEBUILD|VER_PRERELEASE|VER_DEBUG)
FILEOS          VOS__WINDOWS32
FILETYPE        VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE     VFT2_UNKNOWN
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",      VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",  VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",      VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",     VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",   VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1", VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2", VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",      VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",   VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        /* The following line should only be modified for localized versions.     */
        /* It consists of any number of WORD,WORD pairs, with each pair           */
        /* describing a language,codepage combination supported by the file.      */
        /*                                                                        */
        /* For example, a file might have values "0x409,1252" indicating that it  */
        /* supports English language (0x409) in the Windows ANSI codepage (1252). */

        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252

    END
END
```

Is it possible to add your own additional fields as I have described above that will be displayed when the user clicks the file in Windows explorer or be retrieved by the FileVersionInfo function in a program.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Look at [Show Application Title, Version, and Company](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Show_Application_Title,_Version,_and_Company)

Answer (score 2):

From the response to [Custom field in file version in C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132343/custom-field-in-file-version-in-c-project) it is possible, by adding more informaton to the `StringFileInfo` block from the sample in the question. That answer states that the information should be visible in the file properties dialog in Windows Explorer, but I will have to verify that.